# NumPy create a 3D array using other 2 3D arrays and a 1D array to discriminate

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 3D numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array([[[1, 2, 3],
               [4, 5, 6]],

              [[7, 8, 9],
               [10, 11, 12]],

              [[13, 14, 15],
               [16, 17, 18]]])

b = a + 100
```

and 1 1D array:

```
c = np.array([0, 1, 0])
```

I want to create another 3D array which elements are from `a` and `b` based on `c`, i.e. if `c` is `0` take from `a`, if `1` take from `b`.

The result should be:

```
array([[[  1, 2,   3],
        [  4, 5,   6]],

       [[107, 108, 109],
        [110, 111, 112]],

       [[ 13, 14,  15],
        [ 16, 17,  18]]])
```

As I want to use just `numpy` and nothing else, I was trying with `np.where`, but the result is not what I want:

```
>>> np.where(c==0, a, b)

array([[[  1, 102,   3],
        [  4, 105,   6]],

       [[  7, 108,   9],
        [ 10, 111,  12]],

       [[ 13, 114,  15],
        [ 16, 117,  18]]])
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to up `c` to the desired dimension:

```
np.where(c[:, None, None]==0, a, b)
```

```
[[[  1   2   3]
  [  4   5   6]]

 [[107 108 109]
  [110 111 112]]

 [[ 13  14  15]
  [ 16  17  18]]]
```